# How to locate /etc/postgresql/10/main/pg_hba.conf

Tags: psql

i am trying to create a database in postgre sql,then i am getting below error, then i got to know that i need to edit pg_hba.conf file,so where and how to edit this file(i am using ubuntu/linux)

user@name:~$ psql -U postgres
psql: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "postgres"

Comment: Your title contains the exact path to the file, so you know where to find it. Are you asking how to edit a text file on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

so locate your root directory by :

> sudo su

move into the etc directory by:

> cd /etc

to locate the path of your Postgres folder :

> ls p

(note: use tab to complete the path till you get to the pg_hba.conf file)

when you get to the directory of the file type:

> nano pg_hba.conf

do all necessary changes and

> ctrl + o -- save
>
> ctrl + x -- to abort